# Validation for select field angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using `angular2@2.4.1` release. How would i do a `validation` on select `field`?

```
<div class="form-group" [class.has-error] = "schoolError">
            <label class="control-label" for="lang">Select School</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="school"  
            required #school
            [(ngModel)] = "model.school">
                <option value="default">Select a school</option>
                <option *ngFor= "let sch of school">{{sch}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>   

 <button class="btn btn-primary" 
     [disabled] = "form.invalid" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Basically i want to disable the button when the `select field` is invalid?  How do i make the select field `invalid` when no value is selected?

Comment: When is it supposed to be invalid? If `model.school` contains a value, it will be assigned to the `<select>`. Is it then still invalid even when it already has a value and you only have a `required` validator? Or does `model.school` **not** contain an initial value?

Comment: @Shane have you figured it out? What is your solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can make a boolean variable and assign to it `false` as default value. When user chooses any option, it will turn true.

https://plnkr.co/edit/yR5xz4h3llkxHsUQxFJB?p=preview

```
<div>
  <select [(ngModel)]='selected'>
    <option value='one'>Three</option>
    <option value='two'>Two</option>
  </select>
  <button [disabled]='!selected && form.status == 'VALID'>click</button>
</div>
```

`selected:boolean = false;`

Comment: You are applying it to select, [disabled]='!selected' but i want to apply it when the form is invalid...

Comment: @Shane Edited my post.

Comment: why does not select field needs this condition, where as input field whose type text does not?

Comment: @Shane This is just one way to do it my friend :) I bet there are more ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the value in your default option to an empty string:

```
<option [value]="">Select a school</option>
```

Comment: This isn't working as the submit is triggered anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same kind of situation and the below snippet seems to work pretty good.

```
<option [ngValue]="undefined">Select a school</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to implement a `[disabled]="checkSelectFunction()"` on your button and then create a function to check if no value is chosen in the select field.

Answer (score 1):

When adding `ngForm` to your name for your form your validation should work. I assume that is missing, because otherwise your form validation would work as is. So the only thing you would need is to add to your formtag is the aforementioned `ngForm`, like so:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
```

Here's a **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/idEsDwlaozgFagWDsHjx?p=preview)**

Comment: `[(ngModel)] = "model.school"` includes `ngModel`. I don't see how adding `ngModel` again should have any effect.

Comment: Seems your answer wasn't supposed to include `[(ngModel)] = "model.school"` like in your plunker - also the text in your answer suggests that.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You are right. Thanks for pointing that out! my answer was all messed up, must have lost my thoughts along the line.... dementia is setting in :D

Comment: Too much programming is known to lead to temporary dementia sometimes ;-)

Comment: Your Plunker contains `[(ngModel)] = "sch"` but `sch` is only available as iteration variable of the containing `*ngFor`. That is invalid. A parent element can't refer the `*ngFor` variable of a child context.

Comment: It doesn't produce an error in the Plunker but `[(ngModel)] = "sch"` is binding to the components class property `sch` which doesn't exist. Changing it to `foo` does the same http://plnkr.co/edit/nfzBMad6DdcR5nPDI6PB?p=preview Your Plunker is at least misleading by using the same name for `ngModel` and `*ngFor` because these two are not related.

Comment: Yaah. I realized, and deleted my comment, but you are a quick fella and read it before :P Maybe I should just go to bed now :D

Comment: I won't harass you anymore ;-) The answer makes sense now, just the Plunker could use a little tweak.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little late here but the one thing that worked for me was setting the properties to null in the component.

For example,

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="type">Type</label>
  <select
    class="form-control"
    id="type"
    name="type"
    [(ngModel)]="appointment.typeId"
    required>
    <option *ngFor="let aType of types"
        [value]="aType.appointmentTypeId">
        {{aType.type}}
  </select>
```

Component:

```
appointment : Appointment = new Appointment(null);
```

Where model is:

```
export class Appointment {
  constructor(
    public typeId: number
  ) {}
}
```

I hope this helps someone like me who is new to Angular

Answer (score 0):

I tried to give a value to option of the select like

```
<select id="something" formControlName="something">
  <option value="something">Something</option>
</select>
```

The value of the option should not be an empty - if it's empty this required field counts as invalid.